# font-face doesn't work fine on iPad

Tags: ios, css, fonts

I have a problem on my website in safari iOS.
I have two different fonts and one of them doesn't show but only on my iPad.

And when I say doesn't show, it's the text that disappear. But the texts with the other one are fines.

This is my site : http://s189178374.onlinehome.fr/eurosports/index2.php

And the font-face :

```
@font-face {
font-family:    "DIN";
src:    url("fonts/DIN-Regular.eot");
src:    url("fonts/DIN-Regular.eot?#iefix") format("eot"),
        url("fonts/DIN-Regular.woff") format("woff"),
        url("fonts/DIN-Regular.ttf") format("truetype"),
        url("fonts/DIN-Regular.svg#DIN-Regular") format("svg");
font-weight:    normal;
font-style:     normal;
}
@font-face {
font-family:    "DIN";
src:    url("fonts/DIN-Bold.eot");
src:    url("fonts/DIN-Bold.eot?#iefix") format("eot"),
        url("fonts/DIN-Bold.woff") format("woff"),
        url("fonts/DIN-Bold.ttf") format("truetype"),
        url("fonts/DIN-Bold.svg#DIN-Bold") format("svg");
font-weight:    bolder;
font-style:     normal;
}
@font-face {
font-family:    "DIN";
src:    url("fonts/DIN-Medium.eot");
src:    url("fonts/DIN-Medium.eot?#iefix") format("eot"),
        url("fonts/DIN-Medium.woff") format("woff"),
        url("fonts/DIN-Medium.ttf") format("truetype"),
        url("fonts/DIN-Medium.svg#DIN-Medium") format("svg");
font-weight:    bold;
font-style:     normal;
}
@font-face {
font-family:    "DIN";
src:    url("fonts/DIN-Light.eot");
src:    url("fonts/DIN-Light.eot?#iefix") format("eot"),
        url("fonts/DIN-Light.woff") format("woff"),
        url("fonts/DIN-Light.ttf") format("truetype"),
        url("fonts/DIN-Light.svg#DIN-Light") format("svg");
font-weight:    lighter;
font-style:     normal;
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Your font-family name is the same, you need to change it to get other versions of the font (Light, Medium, Bold)

Comment: It doesn't change anything, and I've also have two version of the other font with the same name for the two version and no problem.

Comment: I just test with only one version of my font (by deleting the other versions), and it doesn't change anything neither.

Comment: Make sure your server is sending the appropriate MIME type with those files. I believe Safari for iOS will use the SVG, so it should be sending a mime type of `image/svg+xml` (e.g. add this to your htaccess `AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz`)

Comment: I add the AddType but nothing changes :(

Comment: Can you tell us which two fonts are used exactly (your code here shows four) and which ons is invisible on the iPad. By the way, I'm not at all convinced that `font-weight:lighter` is a valid qualifier in a `@font-face` clause.

Comment: The one that doesn't work is DIN. The code I put is 4 different version of the same font, with different effect (font-weight differences).

Comment: The one that work is DINNextLTPro